# How do I interpret these values in NASA's C-MAPSS dataset files?

Tags: aircraft-design, nasa

I was studying a dual-speed, high-bypass ratio turbofan engine dataset which I happened to obtain from NASA's website. This dataset was generated from C-MAPSS simulator where dataset has nominal and fault files. I studied the user guide doc and some other documents related to the same but I failed to understand the difference between these two files (ie. at the value/ parameter level).

I have following questions, if anyone has used/aware of this dataset please help me:

1. difference between nominal and fault file
2. There are 27 parameteres used, among these which parameters will affect fan, HPC, HPT, LPC, LPT
3. what is the threshold value for these parameters or when do we say that the parameter has reached its max value and above which it would lead to fault condition.

Here is the link where I got the dataset:
[c3.nasa.gov/dashlink/resources/140/](https://c3.nasa.gov/dashlink/resources/140/)

Comment: Can you link to where you obtained the files?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. difference between nominal and fault file

It is found inside the `.tar.gz` file. From the `README` file contained in the page you linked:

> the **Simulation_Info.txt** contains a summary of the number of flights,
>   the fault type that was simulated, if it is nominal or not, and if not
>   what flight and time sample the fault was introduced.

---

> 2. There are 27 parameteres used, among these which parameters will affect fan, HPC, HPT, LPC, LPT

I assume you are asking what are those 27 parameters.
From the `README` file that is found in the page you linked:

[image]

---

> 3. what is the threshold value for these parameters or when do we say that the parameter has reached its max value and above which it would lead to fault condition.

A detailed answer is out of scope for this site, it heavily depends on the failure simulated. The documentation of the various tests should have enough details to understand.

Additionally, hard absolute values are definitely of no use here, different engines will have different characteristics: the numbers valid for the engine simulated here will be applicable to basically no real engine.